# MVC, BBDD, POO Error al pasar datos datos de un formulario a BBDD

Tags: base-de-datos, mvc, java-swing, eclipse, jframe

**Error**

```
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at modelo.BBDD.getConection(BBDD.java:26)
    at modelo.ConsultasBBDD.insertarAlumno(ConsultasBBDD.java:13)
    at controlador.ControladorMenuInsertAlumno.actionPerformed(ControladorMenuInsertAlumno.java:52)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Grupo no encontrado.
Registre primero el grupo.
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.close()" because "this.con" is null
    at modelo.BBDD.cerrrarConexion(BBDD.java:40)
    at modelo.ConsultasBBDD.insertarAlumno(ConsultasBBDD.java:29)
    at controlador.ControladorMenuInsertAlumno.actionPerformed(ControladorMenuInsertAlumno.java:52)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

**Main**

```
Alumno al= new Alumno();
        ConsultasBBDD bbdd= new ConsultasBBDD();
        MenuInsertAl menu= new MenuInsertAl();

        ControladorMenuInsertAlumno control = new ControladorMenuInsertAlumno(al, bbdd, menu);
        control.iniciarMenu();
        menu.setVisible(true);
```

**Conexion BBDD**

```
public class BBDD {
    
    Teclado tcl = new Teclado();
    
    private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Alumno12";
    private final String USERNAME = "root";
    private final String PASSWORD = "manager";
    private Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    Result res = null;
    
    protected Connection getConection() {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return con;

    }

    protected void cerrrarConexion() {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**BBDD**

```
public class ConsultasBBDD extends BBDD{
    private Connection con;
    
    public boolean insertarAlumno(Alumno al) {

        String registrar = "INSERT INTO alumno VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            con = getConection();

            ps = con.prepareStatement(registrar);
            ps.setInt(1, al.getNia());
            ps.setString(2, al.getNombre());
            ps.setString(3, al.getApellidos());
            ps.setInt(4, al.getGenero());
            ps.setString(5, al.getCiclo());
            ps.setString(6, al.getCurso());
            ps.setString(7, al.getGrupo());
            ps.execute();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Grupo no encontrado.\nRegistre primero el grupo.");
            return false;
        } finally {
            cerrrarConexion();
        }

    }
```

**Vista**

```
package vista;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MenuInsertAl extends JFrame {

    public JPanel paneInsertAl;
    public JButton btnRegistrar, btnVolver;
    public ButtonGroup btnGrupo;
    public JTextPane textPaneNia, textPaneNombre, textPaneApellidos, textPaneCiclo, textPaneCurso, textPaneGrupo;
    public JLabel lblRes;

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MenuInsertAl() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        iniciarComponentes();

    }

    private void iniciarComponentes() {
        setBounds(100, 100, 530, 439);
        paneInsertAl = new JPanel();

        paneInsertAl.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));
        paneInsertAl.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(paneInsertAl);
        paneInsertAl.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblBbddAlumno = new JLabel("Insertar Alumno");
        lblBbddAlumno.setFont(new Font("Trebuchet MS", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblBbddAlumno.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        lblBbddAlumno.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblBbddAlumno.setBounds(10, 11, 504, 14);
        paneInsertAl.add(lblBbddAlumno);

        JLabel lblNia = new JLabel("Nia:");
        lblNia.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblNia.setBounds(10, 40, 46, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(lblNia);

        JLabel lblNombre = new JLabel("Nombre:");
        lblNombre.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblNombre.setBounds(10, 65, 72, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(lblNombre);

        JLabel lblApelldios = new JLabel("Apellidos:");
        lblApelldios.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblApelldios.setBounds(10, 90, 72, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(lblApelldios);

        JLabel lblSexo = new JLabel("Sexo:");
        lblSexo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblSexo.setBounds(10, 115, 72, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(lblSexo);

        JLabel lblCiclo = new JLabel("Ciclo:");
        lblCiclo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblCiclo.setBounds(10, 190, 72, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(lblCiclo);

        JLabel lblCurso = new JLabel("Curso:");
        lblCurso.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblCurso.setBounds(10, 215, 72, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(lblCurso);

        JLabel lblGrupo = new JLabel("Grupo:");
        lblGrupo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblGrupo.setBounds(10, 240, 72, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(lblGrupo);

        btnGrupo = new ButtonGroup();

        JRadioButton rdbtnFemenino = new JRadioButton("Femenino");
        rdbtnFemenino.setBounds(80, 115, 109, 23);
        paneInsertAl.add(rdbtnFemenino);
        btnGrupo.add(rdbtnFemenino);
        rdbtnFemenino.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));

        JRadioButton rdbtnMasculino = new JRadioButton("Masculino");
        rdbtnMasculino.setBounds(80, 135, 109, 23);
        paneInsertAl.add(rdbtnMasculino);
        btnGrupo.add(rdbtnMasculino);
        rdbtnMasculino.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));

        JRadioButton rdbtnOtro = new JRadioButton("Otro");
        rdbtnOtro.setBounds(80, 155, 109, 23);
        paneInsertAl.add(rdbtnOtro);
        btnGrupo.add(rdbtnOtro);
        rdbtnOtro.setBackground(new Color(153, 204, 255));

        textPaneNia = new JTextPane();
        textPaneNia.setBounds(80, 40, 170, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(textPaneNia);

        textPaneNombre = new JTextPane();
        textPaneNombre.setBounds(80, 67, 170, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(textPaneNombre);

        textPaneApellidos = new JTextPane();
        textPaneApellidos.setBounds(80, 92, 170, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(textPaneApellidos);

        textPaneCiclo = new JTextPane();
        textPaneCiclo.setBounds(80, 189, 170, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(textPaneCiclo);

        textPaneCurso = new JTextPane();
        textPaneCurso.setBounds(80, 214, 170, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(textPaneCurso);

        textPaneGrupo = new JTextPane();
        textPaneGrupo.setBounds(80, 240, 170, 20);
        paneInsertAl.add(textPaneGrupo);

        btnRegistrar = new JButton("Registrar");
        btnRegistrar.setBounds(77, 333, 89, 23);
        paneInsertAl.add(btnRegistrar);

        btnVolver = new JButton("Volver");
        btnVolver.setBounds(375, 333, 89, 23);
        paneInsertAl.add(btnVolver);

        lblRes = new JLabel("");
        lblRes.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblRes.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblRes.setBounds(114, 291, 275, 32);
        paneInsertAl.add(lblRes);

    }
}
```

**Controlador**

```
public class ControladorMenuInsertAlumno implements ActionListener {
    private Alumno al;
    private ConsultasBBDD consulBBDD;
    private MenuInsertAl menuInserAl;

    public void iniciarMenu() {
        menuInserAl.setTitle("BBDD Alumno12");
        menuInserAl.setResizable(false);
        menuInserAl.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        menuInserAl.setVisible(false);
    }

    public ControladorMenuInsertAlumno(Alumno al, ConsultasBBDD consulBBDD, MenuInsertAl menuInserAl) {
        super();
        this.al = al;
        this.consulBBDD = consulBBDD;
        this.menuInserAl = menuInserAl;
        this.menuInserAl.btnRegistrar.addActionListener(this);
        this.menuInserAl.btnVolver.addActionListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == menuInserAl.btnRegistrar) {

            if (menuInserAl.textPaneNia.getText() == null || menuInserAl.textPaneNombre.getText() == null
                    || menuInserAl.textPaneApellidos.getText() == null || menuInserAl.btnGrupo.getSelection() == null
                    || menuInserAl.textPaneCiclo.getText() == null || menuInserAl.textPaneCurso.getText() == null
                    || menuInserAl.textPaneGrupo.getText() == null) {
                menuInserAl.lblRes.setText("Rellene los campos vacios");
                
            } else {
                al.setNia(Integer.parseInt(menuInserAl.textPaneNia.getText()));
                al.setNombre(menuInserAl.textPaneNombre.getText());
                al.setApellidos(menuInserAl.textPaneApellidos.getText());
                al.setGenero(convertirStrinAChar());
                al.setCiclo(menuInserAl.textPaneCiclo.getText());
                al.setCurso(menuInserAl.textPaneCurso.getText());
                al.setGrupo(menuInserAl.textPaneGrupo.getText());

                if (consulBBDD.insertarAlumno(al)) {
                    menuInserAl.lblRes.setText("Registrado Correctamente");
                    limpiarCampos();
                } else {
                    menuInserAl.lblRes.setText("Error al Registrar");
                    limpiarCampos();
                }
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource() == menuInserAl.btnVolver) {
            Tare12 ta = new Tare12();
            menuInserAl.setVisible(false);
            ta.main(null);

        }

    }

    public void limpiarCampos() {
        menuInserAl.textPaneNia.setText(null);
        menuInserAl.textPaneNombre.setText(null);
        menuInserAl.textPaneApellidos.setText(null);
        menuInserAl.btnGrupo.clearSelection();
        menuInserAl.textPaneCiclo.setText(null);
        menuInserAl.textPaneCurso.setText(null);
        menuInserAl.textPaneGrupo.setText(null);
    }

    private char convertirStrinAChar() {
        String sex = menuInserAl.btnGrupo.toString();
        return sex.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El valor nulo de la conexión se me arreglo al añadir la librería el conector: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/